# Не получается записать в переменную страну

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я хочу записать в переменную страну пользователя, а потом ее использовать вне функции. Я пробовал использовать async и await, но не получается.

```
var country;
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.country); // RU
    country = response.country;
}, "jsonp");
console.log(country); // undefined
```

Как я понял, оно делает запрос и сразу идет к console.log, а при ответе запроса присваивает значение. Как мне сделать, чтобы оно выполнялось последовательно?

Comment: Самый надёжный путь — прочитать весь раздел https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Answer (score 0):

В таком синхронном виде как вы пишете, сделать это не получится.

Вот пример на `async/await`:

```js
async function makeRequest(){
  let country = await new Promise( resolve => {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", response => {
        resolve( response.country );
    }, "jsonp");
  });
  
  console.log(country);
}

makeRequest();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Или так:

```js
(async ()=>{
  
  let country = await new Promise( resolve => {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", response => {
        resolve( response.country );
    }, "jsonp");
  });
  
  console.log(country);
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```